# Cant change cell to right to left. when print datagridview c#

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

I got datagridview in c# (visual studio 2013),and i'm trying to print it(im using RTL language).

I found this class

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13678/The-DataGridViewPrinter-Class

and the only thing im trying to do is change that when i print the datagridview so i will get a right to left in every cell.

I'm understanding the code but i'm not able to change it so it will work..

Thanks for everyone who can help me (and sorry if i got some bad english)

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I added a link to the class with the code. (A demo code)

Comment: Framwork elements have a [`FlowDirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.flowdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Have you checked that?

Comment: No i didnt. How can i check it?

Comment: It looks like if you want to use that [DataGridViewPrinter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13678/The-DataGridViewPrinter-Class), you'll have to make extensive modifications. The method `DrawRows` itself manually goes through the DataGridView and draws them *in order* left-to-right, ignoring the `RightToLeft` setting. I suggest debugging through that class to get an idea of what exactly it's doing.

Comment: Hi i found the problem.

in this "   // Check the CurrentCell alignment and apply it to the CellFormat" note
 i got IF condition
so i put a break point and i found that this line "
TheDataGridView.Columns[CurrentCell].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment.ToString() 
"
is allways set to "NoSet" so it allways getting the Near alignment.
im trying now to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem by edit this line in
 DrawRows function in the class

change this

```
if (TheDataGridView.Columns[CurrentCell].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment.ToString().Contains("Center"))
```

to this

```
if (TheDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment.ToString().Contains("Center"))
```

Working just fine now !